# Move spacy NER entity labels to top or bottom

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am using a spacy visualizer to show labels of each span. I am trying to put the NER labels to the top or bottom of the text for better visualization and comparison. At the moment, I can visualize them with:

```
nlp=spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("This is from Texas Written by Ryan on sunday")
displacy.render(doc,style="ent",jupyter=True)
```

as:
[image]

**How can I move these entity labels to the top or bottom or left of the span?**

The documentation on setting options is [here](https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers#ent); there is no explanation on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can not do it using options but if you want to do it any way then clone Spacy from [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy.git) and go to [this file](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/a79cd3542b3dd667d8a97293462e22ed26a04ee5/spacy/displacy/render.py). There is one function `render_ents` There is HTML Formatting of Renderer there make changes in that Function and Build to test.